# Report metrics during shutdown of spring-boot app

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, metrics, hystrix, netflix

I have a shutdownhook which is successfully executed, but the metrics is not reported. Any advice is appreciated!  
 I guess the issues can be

1. `StatsDMetricWriter` might be disposed before the shutdown hook? How can I verify? Or is there a way to ensure the ordering of the configured singletons?
2. <del>The time gap between metric generation and app shutdown < configured delay. I tried spawning a new Thread with `Thread.sleep(20000)`. But it didn't work</del>

The code snippets are as follows:

```
public class ShutDownHook implements DisposableBean {

    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        registry.counter("appName.deployments.count").dec();
        //Spawned new thread here with high sleep with no effect
    }

}
```

My Metrics Configuration for dropwizard is as below:

```
@Bean
@ExportMetricReader
public MetricRegistryMetricReader metricsDWMetricReader() {
    return new MetricRegistryMetricReader(metricRegistry);
}
@Bean
@ExportMetricWriter
public MetricWriter metricWriter() {      
    return new StatsdMetricWriter(app, host, port);
}
```

The reporting time delay is set as 1 sec:
`spring.metrics.export.delay-millis=1000` 
**EDIT**:
The problem is as below:
`DEBUG 10452 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.a.m.statsd.StatsdMetricWriter      : Failed to write metric. Exception: class java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException, message: Task com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingUdpSender$2@1dd8867d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` -- looks like `ThreadPoolExecutor` is shutdown before the beans are shutdown.

Any Suggestions please?
**EDIT**
`com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsPoller.getCommandJson()` has the following piece of code

```
json.writeNumberField("reportingHosts", 1); // this will get summed across all instances in a cluster
```

I'm not sure how/why the numbers will add up? Where can I find that logic?

Comment: As far as the registering counter for shutdown is concerned, the only way out I found is to monitor this through a separate app, much like hystrix-dashboard. It looks into eureka-registry to know the latest counts of active deployments.